# Скрипт на локальном сервере срабатывает как надо, а на хостинге нет

Tags: php

Заметил, что на локальном сервере скрипт работает как надо, а на хостинге абсолютно работает не правильно, всегда выводит Status Code "OK", версия php на локальном серверов и на хостинге одинаковые.

```
<?
include "conect.php";
$k = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table 1`")or die(mysqli_error($db));
while ($k_k=$k->fetch_assoc()):
$name = $k_k['name'];
$url = $k_k['url'];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($http_code == NULL || $http_code == FALSE || !($http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300)) 
{
echo $name."_Status Code: EROR <br>";
}
else
{
echo $name."_Status Code: OK <br>"; 
}
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: может что то с curl?
Проверьте включена ли библиотека в php_info

Comment: include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect.php"

Comment: да нет через  get_headers такая же чача

Answer (score 0):

Так добавьте **$error = curl_error($ch);** и посмотрите в чём причина!

```
<?
include "conect.php";
$k = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table 1`")or die(mysqli_error($db));
while ($k_k=$k->fetch_assoc()):
$name = $k_k['name'];
$url = $k_k['url'];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($http_code == NULL || $http_code == FALSE || !($http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300)) 
{
echo $name."_Status Code: EROR; message: {$error} <br>";
}
else
{
echo $name."_Status Code: OK <br>"; 
}
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: ничего не выдает, он как будто не понимает что от него хотя, те ссылки которые 100% не работают, через условие выдает "Status Code: OK" , а только парочку "Status Code: EROR" , повторюсь на локальном сервере все работает

Comment: А в $response при этом что находится?

Comment: А у вашего php на серверу установленна библиотека curl ?

Comment: да подключина я, ей пользовался при парсинге, а именно в этом скрипте не работает

Comment: ок $headers = @get_headers('https://user11183.clients-cdnnow.ru/hls/TV1000_HD/master.m3u8'); 
echo $headers[0]; ответ на локальном сервере "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden", а это ответ от хостинга "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"